# Looking for a young adult book written in the 70's or 60's where a young man invents a spaceplane?

Tags: aliens, spaceship, young-adult, story-identification

I am looking for a novel written in the 70's or 60's that had a young man who invented a space plane that had a reflective or diamond coating and used a rare and special element to break the speed of light. With the help of aliens he stops a russian plot to build more space planes and take over the world. thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like it could be Tom Swift.

Comment: I thought so at first as well but after rereading several Swift novels and checking synopsis on several others I couldn't find any matches.I remember checking the book out in the library in the mid 70's that is why I am thinking it could be 60's era book but it could be possibly be 50's also the way it dealt with the cold war.

Comment: I remember reading the first one. Both the protagonist and his sister were inventive geniuses. I think his sister was the physicist who developed the craft's drive. There was a plot element where she'd put a governor/limit on its speed, since she feared he would be reckless. Of course, he had to override it in the climax scene, travel FTL, and reverse time to undo a nuclear missile strike. I probably read this 45 years ago. But I can't recall what I ate for lunch yesterday.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82062/tracking-down-an-old-sci-fi-book

Answer (score 5):

**Space Eagle: Operation Doomsday**

**Space Eagle: Operation Star Voyage**

both by Jack Pearl

In the first, scientific genius and adventurer Paul Girard invents the Swift, an antimatter powered spacecraft using the strange element "Spartanium". It has a hull composed of "fossilized plastic" which reflects hostile laser beams. He makes a secret pact with the President of the United States to be contacted in case of trouble. He is called when a plot is discovered, by the sinister master mind Dr. Lachisis, to create global thermonuclear war.

In the second Paul travels to Alpha Centauri, since the Swift can exceed the speed of light.

Comment: Wow! I read those as a kid, and didn't remember them when reading the question.